# Getting 48 Inappropriate authentication error in openldap

Tags: openldap

I have set up openldap on localhost on Windows and trying to do ldap search with following command

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -b "dc=mydomain,dc=com" "(objectClass=*)"
```

However I get following error

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 48 Inappropriate authentication
```

Following is the content of my slapd.conf file

```
access to *
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com" write
    by * none


database        ldap
suffix          "dc=mydomain,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple binddn=cn=name,cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com credentials=secret mode=none
uri              ldap://server1
rootpw  secret
lastmod off
chase-referrals no
```